# How to copy all files saved in notepad.txt to a different location

Tags: windows-7

I have a notepad.txt document and it contains the file-path of several files on my pc, including their extension 
Example;

C:\Users\Foo\Pictures\Photographs\September\P1030944.jpg

C:\Users\Foo\Videos\Art\Movies\Class\movie.avi

C:\Users\Foo\Music\Jazz\20051.mp3
...etc.

The files in the text document are found in different locations on my pc. Is there a way to move these files from their sources into one destination (example H:\Users\Destination) using their file-path description in the notepad.txt document only? Thanks for your willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with PowerShell with something like this:

```
$inputFile = "c:\temp\notepad.txt"
$targetFolder = "H:\Users\Destination"
Get-Content -Path $inputFile | Copy-Item -Destination $targetFolder
```

You'd have to be a little careful if your notepad.txt file contained something with the same filename, eg:

```
c:\somedirectory\beach.jpg
c:\otherdirectory\beach.jpg
```

Only the last instance in the file would exist in the target location at the end of the process.

Comment: Thanks but yours copy the files instead of moving them. I don't want the files in their source again.Thanks in advance

Comment: Apologies... change the Copy-Item to a Move-Item. 

You will definitely get problems if the filename exists in the target folder because the default behavior of Move-Item is not to overwrite.